# Problems with my MergeSort Algorithm C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, mergesort

```
using System;

namespace MergeSort
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] vektor = { 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 23, 4 };
        static int[] delVektor;
        static int counter = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintVektor(vektor);
            Merge(0, vektor.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            PrintVektor(vektor);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void PrintVektor(int[] vektor)
        {
            foreach (var item in vektor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString() + " ");
            }
        }

        static void Merge(int start, int stop)
        {
            if (start >= stop)
                return;

            int middle = (start + stop) / 2;

            Merge(start, middle);
            Merge(middle + 1, stop);

            delVektor = new int[stop - start + 1];

            int indexStart = start;
            int indexStop = middle + 1;

            while (indexStart <= middle && indexStop <= stop)
            {
                if (vektor[indexStart] < vektor[indexStop])
                {
                    delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStart];
                    indexStart++;
                    counter++;
                }

                else
                {
                    delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStop];
                    indexStop++;
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            while (indexStart <= middle)
            {
                delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStart];
                indexStart++;
                counter++;
            }

            while (middle <= stop)
            {
                delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStop]; // <---- here i get index out of range
                indexStop++;
                counter++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= delVektor.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                vektor[start + i] = delVektor[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is i get an index out of range exception( i have commented in the code),

```
while (middle <= stop) {
  delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStop]; // <---- here i get index out of range
  indexStop++; counter++;
}
```

I cant figure it out

I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have been staring at this code for so long now that i just want to throw the computer out of the window as soon as I try to fix it.

Comment: MergeSort is generally broken into two methods, `mergesort` and `merge`. You seem to have combined them into a single method that looks confusing. Have a look at the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort it has good information. Also I imagine you are recursing infinitely.

Comment: If this is a homework type of question, please tag it as such.

Comment: what doesn't work? ie what was the result and what did you expect

Comment: sorry, i am new here and i should explain my problem.

Comment: sorry, i am new here and i should explain my problem. THe thing is i get an index out of range exception( i have commented in the code), while (middle <= stop)
            {
                delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStop]; // <---- here i get index out of range
                indexStop++;
                counter++;
            }
I cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using an index into an array and you increment that index you need to test whether that index is actually within the bounds of the array (0-based indexes for you code).

Do you test your index ensuring that it cannot run out of bounds?

Comment: yes this i homework, but i cant edit it with a tag.. no should i try some if-statements?

Comment: Isn't part of being a good programmer the ability to find the answer on the internet anyway possible?  :)

Comment: @moofoo no you should not try to fix the symptom by adding some (arbitrary) ifs you should look at you logic and see if it's correct. Do your loops end when you expect them to?

Comment: i checked a link that someone sent and, that was the thing..i never set the index back to zero....thx everyone for your help....

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
if (start >= stop)
            return;

        int middle = (start + stop) / 2;

        Merge(start, middle);
        Merge(middle + 1, stop);
```

You are not supposed to `return` if `start>=stop` you are simply supposed to skip the merge segments. Here is a fix:

```
int middle = (start + stop) / 2;
if (start < stop){

        Merge(start, middle);
        Merge(middle + 1, stop);
}
//...put the rest of the code which you already have here
```

Comment: If you are still having problem, you should check out the mergesort on Geekviewpoint: http://geekviewpoint.com/Sort_Algorithms_in_java/

Comment: i have tried this fix and i still get indexOutOfRange when my temp array is 1 big..my counter is 1 asswell is that the problem? have you got it to work?

Comment: You should follow the link to geekviewpoint. There is an easy to follow implementation there: geekviewpoint.com/Sort_Algorithms_in_java . Either scroll down or search for mergesort.

Answer (score 1):

fixed your code. (perhaps)

```
using System;

namespace MergeSort{
    class Program{
        static int[] vektor = { 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 23, 4 };
        static int[] delVektor;
        static int counter = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args){
            PrintVektor(vektor);
            Merge(0, vektor.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            PrintVektor(vektor);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void PrintVektor(int[] vektor){
            foreach (var item in vektor)
                Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        static void Merge(int start, int stop){
            if (start >= stop)
                return;

            int middle = (start + stop) / 2;

            Merge(start, middle);
            Merge(middle + 1, stop);

            delVektor = new int[stop - start + 1];
            counter = 0;//add

            int indexStart = start;
            int indexStop = middle + 1;

            while (indexStart <= middle && indexStop <= stop){
                if (vektor[indexStart] < vektor[indexStop]){
                    delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStart];
                    indexStart++;
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStop];
                    indexStop++;
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            while (indexStart <= middle){
                delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStart];
                indexStart++;
                counter++;
            }

            while (indexStop <= stop){//edit
                delVektor[counter] = vektor[indexStop];
                indexStop++;
                counter++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= delVektor.Length - 1; i++){
                vektor[start + i] = delVektor[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catches!  The counter was never being reset to 0 and that while loop was checking a condition that would never change in the body of the loop!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the condition you are using in the loop where you are getting the exception. Note that if the condition is true on first entry, it will be true forever. The fix should then be obvious. (Hint: nothing in the loop body should be changed.)